# Are the contents of git blob encrypted?

Tags: git

I am reading about the git internals and it says that a blob just contains the content of the file. So I went on doing the following

```
echo "hello world" > a.txt
git add a.txt
```

The `.git/object` had a folder `3b18e512dba79e4c8300dd08aeb37f8e728b8dad`.
Upon opening it, there was junk value in it. But running the following command,

```
git cat-file -p 3b18e512dba79e4c8300dd08aeb37f8e728b8dad
// hello world
```

So the cat-file command is definitely knowing how to parse the blob object. What is that junk value in the blob and how does `cat-file` interpret it. I'm sure it is the content of the file, but in what format is it written as?

Comment: Nope. The file is addressed using the hash. The blob contains the file content which is compressed using zlib as mentioned below

Comment: Sorry, you read it right, the file is simply compressed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a case of blobs, its content represents blob header and content. You can check this with:

```
$ openssl zlib -d -in .git/objects/3b/18e512dba79e4c8300dd08aeb37f8e728b8dad
blob 12hello world
```

for example.

Answer (score 1):

In git a blob is the content of a file.   All blobs are compressed with zlib and delta compression in git (so revisions don't eat up massive amounts of space), which is why blobs are unreadable.  The name of a blob is its SHA-1 hash.

Comment: "In git a blob is the content of a file"--not quite. Git adds a header to a file before it compresses it and officially makes it a blob. The header is composed of the string "blob", plus a space, plus the length of the file (in bytes) expressed as an ASCII number (such as 123), followed by a null-termination character, followed by the content of the file in question. The SHA-1 is computed from the file contents + header--before zlib compression.